# Can I prevent a LINQ DataContext from using a transaction when a TransactionScope is present?

Tags: linq, transactionscope

I'm using a `TransactionScope` in a model controller class that coordinates several lower level, data access classes. The data access classes each use their own LINQ `DataContext`, and thanks to the magic of `TransactionScope`, they all participate in the same transaction if one is present.

Under normal circumstances, this is perfect and everything works. However, I've added an activity logging class and one of the places it can write to is the database. Unfortunately, it automatically picks up on the `TransactionScope` and if the transaction gets rolled back, so do all the log entries.

I've checked the `Transaction` property of the `DataContext` and it's null, as expected, so I'm not sure how to tell it to ignore the `TransactionScope`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your logging class, wrap your `using(new datacontext())` into:

```cs
using (var s = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress)) {

}
```

Comment: This is exactly right. Creating a new transaction scope with the suppress option causes any contexts within it to ignore any outer transaction scopes. Thanks!